# How to map Complex type using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

Automapper with complex nested mapping. I am trying to map mydestinationArrayField and
dest1Array, here source objectlist to be copied to dest1array.

here are my classes for source and destination.

```
namespace AutomapperDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SourceObject request = new SourceObject()
                {
                    sourceTypeField = "1",
                    SourceObj1Field = new SourceObj1
                    {
                        SourceObj1Id = "1",
                        SourceObjListss = new List<SourceInnerObjList>
                       {

                       new SourceInnerObjList
                       {
                          SourceObjListItem1Id = 1


                       },
                       new SourceInnerObjList
                       {
                           SourceObjListItem1Id = 2

                       }
                   }

                    }
                };
                var mapper = CreateMapper();
                DestinationObject destination = new DestinationObject();
                destination = mapper.Map<DestinationObject>(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        public static IMapper CreateMapper()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
                cfg.CreateMap<SourceObject, DestinationObject>()
               .ForMember(dest => dest.destinationTypeField, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.sourceTypeField))
               .ForMember(dest => dest.destinationObjectArrayField, o => o.MapFrom(src => new destinationObjectArray()
               {
                   mydestinationArrayField = src.SourceObj1Field.SourceObjListss.Select(x => x.SourceObjListItem1Id).FirstOrDefault().ToString(), //this gives error

                   //dest1Array = src.SourceObj1Field.SourceObjListss // here source objectlist to be copied to dest1array

               }));
            });

            return config.CreateMapper();
        }

    }
}


namespace Automapper
{
    public class SourceObject
    {
        public string sourceTypeField;
        public SourceObj1 SourceObj1Field { get; set; }
    }
    public class SourceObj1
    {
        public string SourceObj1Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<SourceInnerObjList> SourceObjListss { get; set; }
    }

    public class SourceInnerObjList
    {
        public int SourceObjListItem1Id { get; set; }
        public int SourceObjListItem2d { get; set; }

    }
    public class SourceInnerObj2List
    {
        public int? mycount { get; set; }
        public int? yourcount { get; set; }
    }

}


namespace Automapper
{
    public class DestinationObject
    {
        public string destinationTypeField;
        public destinationObjectArray[] destinationObjectArrayField;
    }

    public class destinationObjectArray
    {
        public string mydestinationArrayField;

        public string myField1;

        public destinationInnerObject1Array[] dest1Array;

        public destinationInnerObject2Array[] dest2Array;
    }
    public class destinationInnerObject1Array
    {
        public string destinationInnerObjectItem11;
        public string destinationInnerObjectItem21;
    }
    public class destinationInnerObject2Array
    {
        public string categoryTypeField;

        public string valueField;

        public string NumberField;
    }
}
```

While executing the mapping i am getting "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping."

No matter how I configure ignores or custom mappings it seems to not like this nesting. Any Automapper experts out there who could tell me how a mapping with a complex object like this could be done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your second ForMember doesn't work:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.destinationObjectArrayField, o => o.MapFrom(src => new destinationObjectArray() //...
```

Because in you're defining your map to return destinationObjectArray()
and not destinationObjectArray[]!

So there is a map like:

> destinationObjectArrayField -> destinationObjectArray()

and there is no map like:

> destinationObjectArrayField -> destinationObjectArray[]

And Automapper is telling you that.

You should do something like this:

```
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceObject, DestinationObject>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.destinationTypeField, o => o.MapFrom(src => src.sourceTypeField))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.destinationObjectArrayField,
                    o => o.MapFrom(
                        src => src.SourceObj1Field
                            .SourceObjListss
                            .Select(x => new destinationObjectArray
                            {
                                myField1 = $"first_id: {x.SourceObjListItem2d} second_id: {x.SourceObjListItem1Id}"
                            })
                            .ToArray()
                    ));
    });
```

Also cleaning and formatting code is highly suggested, it's seems like you've simply got lost in it! IDE's can help with that.

Comment: This mapping works, but i get multiple destinationObjectArrayField  , i need destinationObjectArrayField [0] and destinationInnerObject1Array will be a list .destinationObjectArrayField [0].destinationInnerObject1Array

Comment: Can you suggest me how to change this to "destinationObjectArrayField expects only one value say the firstordefault value (that means the array will have only one item and the inside object destinationInnerObject1Array will have all the properties in the list) and destinationInnerObject1Array[] will have all the items from SourceObjListss. ie the line //dest1Array = src.SourceObj1Field.SourceObjListss on my example

Comment: CI have added firstordefault to get only one item but it gives custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type.